# why I can't get the google chrome CSS Grid Inspector?

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-devtools, devtools

I've been trying to use the CSS grid inspector for google chrome dev tools. However, I can get neither the **grid** label aside of the element(as the dev tools must show) nor the **Layout** panel where I should be able to play with grid gaps, rows, etc.

How can I enable/use them?

Google Chrome Version 86.0.4240.75 (Official Build) (64-bit)

Article I've tried to follow: https://developers.google.com/web/tools/chrome-devtools/css/grid

Comment: Enable it in devtools -> settings -> experiments.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The way to enable the feature isn't documented very well.

1. Select `Control+Shift+I` (Windows, Linux) or `Command+Option+I` (macOS)
2. Select `Shift+?` to show the Settings panel
3. Navigate to Experiments and...
4. Check "Enable new CSS Grid debugging features (configuration options available in Layout sidebar pane in Elements after Restart)"

After restarting the Dev Tools you should see small grid-tags in the Element Explorer and the new Layout pane in the Dev Tools sidebar.

HTH

*BTW it should be default by version 87...*

Comment: is there a solution for chrome 114? Enable new CSS Grid debugging features (configuration options available in Layout sidebar pane in Elements after Restart) is gone now

Comment: In Chrome 114 the feature is built-in. An element containing a grid has a litte pill-badge with the word "grid" inside behind the HTML-Tag in the developer-tool's "Elements" view. Just click on the badge with the word "grid" and it turns "active" and shows you the stuff you need within your browser.

Answer (score 2):

Took me a while as well, but here's the step-by-step:

[Open Developer Tools and click on the cogwheel (Settings)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0Eu1p.png)

[Select the tab Experiments and then check "Enable new CSS Grid debugging features"](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Nu9Mk.jpg)

[The Layout tab appears as the last item](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NVQ0p.png)

Comment: Hey, thanks for your instructions. Could you add properly links pls? I think the ones you added are broken

Comment: @Jhonatan, the links were images I added to the body of the answer. The site uploads them to imgur and generates links. They were just screenshots illustrating the steps.[step 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0Eu1p.png), [step 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Nu9Mk.jpg), [step 3](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NVQ0p.png)

Answer (score 0):

That's wonderful, but I haven't "Enable new CSS Grid debugging features" checkbox. I have layout and other features, but Grid inspector not working. Checked many times. Chrome 122.0.6261.131 (Official Build) (64-bit)